# Closing Drawer On Logout in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

In my `React Native` app, I have a `StackNavigator` that handles the login process and a `DrawerNavigator` which is available for authenticated users.

When I log out of the app and then log back in, I see that the drawer is still open. When I click to log out, I invoke the `handleClickLogOut()` function in my `Navigator` component -- see below. I thought by accessing the `MainMenuDrawer`, I could access `closeDrawer()` method but I don't see it there.

How can I close the drawer on log out in this code?

Here's the `Navigator` component:

```
const LogInStack = new createStackNavigator();
const MainMenuDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();

class Navigator extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClickLogOut = this.handleClickLogOut.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        if (this.props.isAuthenticatedUser && !this.props.isAuthenticated)
            this.props.actions.setIsAuthenticated(true);
    }

    handleClickLogOut() {

        removeAuthenticationData()
            .then(() => {

                return this.props.actions.setIsAuthenticated(false);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                {
                    this.props.isAuthenticated
                    ? <MainMenuDrawer.Navigator drawerContent={(navigation) => <DrawerContent member={this.props.member} navigation={navigation} handleClickLogOut={this.handleClickLogOut} />}>
                        <MainMenuDrawer.Screen name="Home" component={Dashboard} />
                        <MainMenuDrawer.Screen name="ToDoList" component={ToDoList} />
                      </MainMenuDrawer.Navigator>
                    : <LogInStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
                        <LogInStack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={Login} />
                      </LogInStack.Navigator>
                }
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you pass a callback function to handleClickLogOut from the DrawerContent and call it? then it will be inside the navigation context right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sam here is the solution brother.

```
import {DrawerActions} from '@react-navigation/native'
```

then you can call in **DrawerContent.js** file with this:

```
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())
```

Hope this will help you .

Here is my Real Code in **DrawerContent.tsx** file

[image]

Comment: I think his problem is calling the closedrawer from handleClickLogOut which is outside the navigation context

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan you are correct brother. That right, i suggested him to called in DrawerContent.js file